# AngularJS: model is not binding

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular Modal and when I send the input to the modal and set the scope variable, I cannot see the binding happening.

Here is the code:

Note: I am yet to implement the close function in the controller for the modal.

Code for showing the modal:

```
$scope.approveReq = function (id) {
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: "/app/mis/jobno/createjno.html",
        controller: "CreateJnoCtrl",
        inputs: { input: id }
    }).then(function (modal) {
        // The modal object has the element built, if this is a bootstrap modal
        // you can call 'modal' to show it, if it's a custom modal just show or hide
        // it as you need to.
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function (result) {
            $scope.message = result ? "You said Yes" : "You said No";
        });
    });
};
```

HTML of the modal

```
<div id="jobcreate" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form name="jobcreate">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new Job</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <fieldset class="form-group row">
                        <label for="iBranchId" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Branch</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="jobno.BranchId" id="iBranchId">
                                <option ng-repeat="b in branches" value="{{b.org_id}}">{{b.org_location}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <label for="iJobType" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Job Type</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" style="width:250px" ng-required="true" ng-model="jobno.iJobType" id="iJobType">
                                <option ng-repeat="jt in jobTypes" value="{{jt.iJobTypeId}}">{{jt.vJobType}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group row">
                        <label for="ClieintId" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Customer</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="ClieintId" ng-required="true" ng-model="selClient" ng-change="getlocs()">
                                <option ng-repeat="c in clientList" value="{{c.Id}}">{{c.Name}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <label for="vClientLoc" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Location</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="vClientLoc" ng-required="true" ng-model="jobno.vClientLoc">
                                <option ng-repeat="l in clientLocs" value="{{l.Loc_Id}}">{{l.Loc_Name}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group row">
                        <label for="ContractId" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Contract No</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="jobno.ContractId" id="ContractId" ng-options="c.Contract_Id as (c.Contract_No) for c in contracts"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-show="createdJobNo">{{createdJobNo}} Created!</div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" id="createJobNo" ng-if="!jobcreate.$pristine" ng-disabled="jobcreate.$invalid" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createJobNo()">Create Job Number</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller for the modal

```
angular.module('trg-app.mis').controller('CreateJnoCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', 'ClientDataService', 'input', 'close', function ($http, $scope, ClientDataService, input, close) {

    //create Job No

    //Get input if any
    $scope.jobReq;

    //Empty Job
    $scope.jobno = {
        iJobType: null,
        vClientLoc: null,
        vJobNo: null,
        iRefJobNo: 0,
        vRemark: null,
        ContractId: 1,
        UpdatedBy: 1,
        BranchId: null
    };
    if (input != undefined) {
        $scope.jobReq = input;
        console.log("Input Received for JobReq: ", input);
        $scope.jobno = {
            iJobType: $scope.jobReq.Job_Type,
            vClientLoc: $scope.jobReq.Client_Location,
            vJobNo: null,
            iRefJobNo: 0,
            vRemark: null,
            ContractId: 1,
            UpdatedBy: 1,
            BranchId: $scope.jobReq.Org_Location
        };
    }
    else {
        $scope.jobno = {
            iJobType: null,
            vClientLoc: null,
            vJobNo: null,
            iRefJobNo: 0,
            vRemark: null,
            ContractId: 1,
            UpdatedBy: 1,
            BranchId: null
        };
    }

    $scope.branches;
    $scope.getBranches = function () {
        $http.get("/api/orgdetails/").then(
            function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                $scope.branches = resp.data;
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log("Error: ", err);
            }
        );
    };
    $scope.getBranches();

    $scope.jobTypes = {};
    $scope.getJobTypes = function () {
        console.log("getting Job Types");
        $http.get('/api/jobtypes/').then(
                function (resp) {
                    console.log('Response: ', resp);
                    $scope.jobTypes = resp.data;
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log("Error: ", err);
                }
            );
    };
    $scope.getJobTypes();

    $scope.clientList;
    //get minimal client list and bind to the side bar
    $scope.getClients = function () {
        ClientDataService.GetClientList()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.clientList = response;
        });
    };
    $scope.getClients();

    $scope.clientLocs;
    $scope.selClient;
    //locs should be brought in when we go to the location editing
    $scope.getlocs = function () {
        console.log("$scope.selClient: ", $scope.selClient)
        if ($scope.selClient != undefined) {
            ClientDataService.GetClientLocs($scope.selClient)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.clientLocs = response;
            });
            $scope.getContracts($scope.selClient);
        }
    };
    //$scope.getlocs();

    $scope.contracts;
    $scope.getContracts = function (ClientId) {
        $http.get('/api/Contracts/client/' + ClientId).then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.contracts = response.data;
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting contracts: ", error);
            }
            );
    };

    $scope.createdJobNo;
    $scope.createJobNo = function () {
        if ($scope.jobno) {
            $scope.createdJobNo = null;
            console.log($scope.jobno);
            $http.post('/api/jobnos/', $scope.jobno).then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log("Job Created: ", response.data.vJobNo);
                    //$scope.jobno.vJobNo = response.data.vJobNo;
                    $scope.createdJobNo = response.data.vJobNo;
                    //TODO: if Job is created from Req, update additional info
                    //$scope.initJCreate();
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("Error!");
                }
                );
        }
    };


}]);
```

Comment: Isn't `input` automatically created on the `$scope` in your modal controller? So you'd need `$scope.jobReq = $scope.input` instead of just `$scope.jobReq = input`.

Comment: have you tried using the controllerAs, perhaps not your fix, but I would recommend that